# How do I get the date/requestTime/timestamp in Mapping Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

Looking at the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-context-reference.html) it appears there is no way of getting the `requestTime` from the context variable.

Is there any other way, apart from using a lambda resolver, to get that value?

I know it is possible when using [API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html), so surely there is a way. Am I looking at the wrong thing?

Thanks

Julien

Answer (score 15, accepted):

(I work on the AWS AppSync team)

You're right, we do not yet expose the request time inside the mapping template.

May I ask what your use case is?

This is valuable feedback, I'm going to make sure this gets seen by the team. I will update this thread as we have more information.

**UPDATE**: We now support extracting the current timestamp via mapping template helper methods.
Here are a few functions that can help you achieve what you need:

```
$util.time.nowISO8601()                                            : 2018-02-06T19:01:35.749Z
$util.time.nowEpochSeconds()                                       : 1517943695
$util.time.nowEpochMilliSeconds()                                  : 1517943695750
$util.time.nowFormatted("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ")                    : 2018-02-06 19:01:35+0000
$util.time.nowFormatted("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ", "+08:00")          : 2018-02-07 03:01:35+0800
$util.time.nowFormatted("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ", "Australia/Perth") : 2018-02-07 03:01:35+0800
```

The complete reference is available on the [Resolver Mapping Template Utility Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-util-reference.html) page.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick answer.

I just want to add a `createdAt` and `updatedAt` attributes. The mapping alone is sufficient in most cases (basic CRUD operation). But for me, not being able to get the time means I have to use a lamdba for my write operation (which isn't too bad, let's be honest).

Thanks

Comment: @Julienmachon you could also pass the timestamp through as an argument for your GraphQL mutations and then the Mapping Template can grab that from $context.arguments and store it directly in DynamoDB

Comment: Hey @Richard. I guess I don't necessarily want to add yet another argument to my mutation input. Plus, I would never trust a date coming from the client without validation. Also comes issues like time zone, etc... So unfortunately, this would not work for me.

Comment: @Tinou you guys should update the appsync documentation, it doesn't include the time variable.

Comment: @Munib I updated my answer with the correct link to the time helpers. Thanks!

Comment: @Tinou Thanks for quick reply, I appreciate it. I can't wrap my head around how would I go about getting the exact date for the end of the current week (7 Days)? Say that today is March 27, 2019, I would like to calculate the value of April 2, 2019 (Including the current day).  Given the util time functions, I can't see how one would go about doing this.

Comment: If you need to add days you could work with the epoch seconds  and add the days in seconds. If you’re looking for the utility to tell you when the end of the week is, then we don’t offer these utilities. It’s good feedback though and I’ll make sure the team sees this.